# export shapefile to spatialite hangs qgis

Tags: qgis-2, spatialite

I have a shapefile layer containing 9 points. The attribute table has a string column (max 18 chars) and a real column. The .dbf file is ~4KB, all the other files are 1KB. I right-click on the layer, select Save As and set the type to Spatialite, assign a file name, then click OK. The process just runs and runs. No error. If I look at the file, it's growing about 2KB every couple of seconds. I killed it when it passed 2.5MB. I've tried this a couple of times and the same thing happens consistently.

Any suggestions about what to try next?

[edit]
The problematic shapefile can be found [here](http://www.CorazonDelBosque.us/qgis_spatialite_test.zip)

QGIS version    2.0.1-Dufour
QGIS code revision  d94c044
Compiled against Qt 4.8.5
Running against Qt  4.8.5
Compiled against GDAL/OGR   1.10.0
Running against GDAL/OGR    1.10.1
Compiled against GEOS   3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2
Running against GEOS    3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 r3921
PostgreSQL Client Version   9.2.4
SpatiaLite Version  4.1.1
QWT Version 5.2.3
PROJ.4 Version  480
QScintilla2 Version 2.7.2

Windows 7 Pro, 64 bit

Comment: Can you share the data? Looks like a bug in QGIS, so probably should be reported to the developers.

Comment: Which version of QGIS and which OS are you using?

Comment: Tested this in QGIS 2.2 on OS X 10.8 (64 bit) -> generated .sqlite in ~ 10 seconds. Tested on QGIS 2.3-dev on Ubuntu 12.04 and it gives the same problem you describe.

Comment: [#8340](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/8340) could be related... You should upgrade if you can and try on 2.2. Simbamangu has tried it on master, possibly a regression.

Comment: I've added a link to the dataset, plus all the output from Help->About for the version of qgis I'm running. Upgrading to 2.2 is problematic because I need to stay in sync with a larger team that is running this version.

Comment: I'm getting an error trying to load the shapefile into QGIS 2.2 (Win 7 64b) before even getting to spatialite. ??

Comment: mea culpa. Apparently I omitted the .shx file when I zipped up the shapefile. It should work now. (and I should have checked before uploading)